# Set a Footer at the Bottom of the Browser Regardless of Page Height

Tags: html, css, web

1. The image below represents the footer
2. The black arrow represents the expandable content

[image]

Div snippet looks as the following:

```
<div id="footer_wrap">
    <div id="footer-left"></div>
    <div id="footer-middle"></div>
    <div id="footer-right"></div>
</div>
```

The width of the whole footer is 980px
The height of the footer is 124px

I'm using Firefox.

**How can i set my footer stuck the bottom of the browser regardless of the height of the page.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: Link is dead / leads to scam

Answer (score 0):

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BKqnH/3/)

Answer (score 0):

use position fixed, this will position relative to the window so that scrolling will not affect where it appears.

```
   position: fixed;

   bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally find that this sticky footer is a lot more reliable than css sticky footer:

[Man in Blue - footerStickAlt](http://www.themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2005/08/29/)